# C# classes not being called when using MongoDB project

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 website and I am trying to integrate some Mongodb functionality (just experimenting for now). I am using this [mongodb project](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-azure/) as I am also trying to deploy to Azure, this project provides connection utilities for connecting to the mongodb worker role. I have a MovieController with the following constructor:

```
public class MovieController : Controller
    {
        MongoMovieHelper _movies;
        public MovieController()
        {
            _movies = new MongoMovieHelper();
        }
}
```

This in turn calls the class:

```
 public class MongoMovieHelper
    {
        public MongoCollection<Movie> Collection { get; private set; }

        public MongoMovieHelper()
        {
            MongoServerSettings serverSettings = ConnectionUtilities.GetConnectionSettings();
            MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(serverSettings);
            MongoDatabase db = server["movies"];
            Collection = db.GetCollection<Movie>(typeof(Movie).Name.ToLower());
        }
...
```

When trying to load any page from the Movie controller I get an internal server error in the Chrome debugger.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

So I tried debugging in visual studio. The controller constructor gets hit, but any breakpoints within MongoMovieHelper do not, and trying to Step into just hits the controller constructor again. The stack trace displays the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'MongoDB.Driver, Version=1.4.2.4500,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f686731cfb9cc103' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Previously I had another class which makes the Mongodb connection so Controller calls MongoMovieHelper which calls MongoDBHelper. In this case, both the controller and MongoMovieHelper were being called, but MongoDBHelper was not, so I believe the problem lies within the mongodb connection.

This is probably some rookie mistake but I just can't figure out what the problem might be, any ideas?

Comment: What error do you get? And try to rebuild all. If breakpoints don't get set it's usually because the code is out of sync

Comment: Tried rebuilding but still have the same problem, I edited the question with the full error. Thanks.

Comment: Try cycling mongodb and your web process.  You should only have one Databse instance per application per the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#csharp-driver-tutorial). Is possible all connections are in use as the default is 5.

Comment: That's not the full error, get the stacktrace

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, see edit for the full error. Sorry for taking so long to reply, had to go out of town for the day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to recreate your problem using the latest version of the official mongodb c# driver but I could not.

I am using the latest official driver available on NuGet:

I changed your code to use non-obsolete methods to get the server object:

```
public MongoMovieHelper()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(MongoUrl.Create("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var db = server["movies"];
        Collection = db.GetCollection<Movie>(typeof (Movie).Name.ToLower());
    }
```

So if you are not using the official driver then please use it:

get using the following command:

```
Install-Package mongocsharpdriver
```

Then try and change your code to look something like mine and then see if it works.

The error you are getting suggests you are either using an old version of the official driver, or you aren't using the official driver at all.

Note: uninstall the old driver, either through the nuget console (/ui), alternatively remove the binary ref and clean your project ensuring that you don't have any bin dll left hanging around.

Comment: The problem was resolved when I reinstalled the Azure SDK and also the C# driver for all the projects in the solution. Thanks for the help :)